# Jquery $.get() manipulating data resulting from query in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, http-get

I have a `$.get()` statement, which returns this (result from a `console.log()`):

`{"desc":"asdasda","dateD":"2012-08-31","dateE":"2012-09- 01","image":"fasdasdasd","categorie":"3"}`

Now when I try, in Javascript, to manipulate the array, everything holds an `undefined` or `null` value:

```
var image = data.image;
desc = data.desc;
dateD = data.dateD;
dateF = data.dateE;
image = data.image;
categorie = data.categorie;
```

Note: the `DateF= data.dateE` is not a mistake.

Note2: Those statements are all held within the `function (data){}` function contained in the `$.get()`.

All those assignments return `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? I have read and re-read the [official jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), without success.

Comment: Get is cool, but it doesn't expect the object to be returned in JSON. console.log() natively detects the type of array, object, or string passed, and it parses it accordingly. Which it why it looks good. If you want to getJSON, then use `$.getJSON`, otherwise, use $.ajax() and set the `dataType: json`.

Comment: Have you set the `dataType` to JSON? Your `console.log()` show a Javascript object literal expressed as a string - is it still just a string?

Comment: Are you using [$.parseJSON(data)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I suggest you post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @Ghillied Neal's got the jist of it. Accept his!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy you can also set the datatype to `json` with the regular `$.get(...)` function. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11831159/561731)

Comment: @Neal Yep. I'm just a hater. all $.serverRequests are just a wrapper for $.ajax anyway. If you're going to use shortcode, use it as intended. $.get should be used if you want to get plain text, strings, or arrays, getJSON should be used if you want to get JSON. that's just how I program. :p

Comment: @Ohgodwhy then what do you do for `postJSON`? :-P I just do `$.post(url, postData, fn, 'json');` :-)

Comment: @Neal I never use $.post for JSON, I use $.ajax. like I said, I r h8r. Anyway, I told him to accept your answer. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set the `dataType` of the return to `json`.

If you don't do this, the result data may be a **string** and you will need to use `JSON.parse(data)` to turn it into a usable object.

---

For example:

```javascript
$.get(url, getData, function(data){
    //your fn...
}, 'json');
```